# Redirection of a path url to its base url

Tags: nginx, redirect, devops, amazon-cloudfront, nginx-location

I need to redirect some urls to their original base url, for eg if if i have the below url
https://example.com/path/to/something
it should be redirected to the below
https://example.com
Any way i can acheive this on nginx level or cloudfront level?
I tried the below
**rewrite ^(/path/to/something)(.*)$   https://example.com/$2 permanent;**
but did not work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in CloudFront, you can use CloudFront Functions (lightweight JavaScript functions that execute at the edge). Here is an example of doing redirects based on country - you can modify based on your needs:
https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-cloudfront-functions/tree/main/redirect-based-on-country

Comment: Hi, thanks! I actually solved it with a permanent direction in location block like this
location = /path/to/something {
    return 301 https://example.com;
}